# How to wait till Web Page is loaded C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using shellexecutex to open the web browser from c++ program. But it doesn't waits for web page to load. Because of this if another web request comes to the web browser before loading the initial request, then an application error is shown in the web page.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO rSEI = { 0 };
rSEI.cbSize = sizeof(rSEI);
rSEI.lpVerb = "open";
rSEI.lpFile = (LPCSTR)sURL;
rSEI.lpParameters = 0;
rSEI.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
rSEI.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShellExecuteEx(&rSEI);   
WaitForSingleObject(rSEI.hProcess, INFINITE);
DWORD dwCode;
GetExitCodeProcess(rSEI.hProcess, &dwCode);
```

How to wait till Web Page is loaded C++?
Please assist me to solve this problem